# list indices (DateTimeIndex) must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `DateTimeIndex`

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-08-19', '2023-02-19', '2023-08-19', '2024-02-19',
               '2024-08-19', '2025-02-19', '2025-08-19', '2026-02-19',
               '2026-08-19', '2027-02-19', '2027-08-19', '2028-02-19',
               '2028-08-19', '2029-02-19', '2029-08-19', '2030-02-19',
               '2030-08-19', '2031-02-19', '2031-08-19', '2032-02-19',
               '2032-08-19', '2033-02-19', '2033-08-19', '2034-02-19',
               '2034-08-19', '2035-02-19', '2035-08-19', '2036-02-19',
               '2036-08-19', '2037-02-19', '2037-08-19', '2038-02-19',
               '2038-08-19', '2039-02-19', '2039-08-19', '2040-02-19',
               '2040-08-19', '2041-02-19', '2041-08-19', '2042-02-19',
               '2042-08-19', '2043-02-19', '2043-08-19', '2044-02-19',
               '2044-08-19', '2045-02-19', '2045-08-19', '2046-02-19',
               '2046-08-19', '2047-02-19', '2047-08-19', '2048-02-19',
               '2048-08-19', '2049-02-19', '2049-08-19', '2050-02-19',
               '2050-08-19', '2051-02-19', '2051-08-19', '2052-02-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=6>')
```

Given by :

```
dates = pd.date_range("2022-08-19", "2052-02-19", freq=pd.DateOffset(months=6))
```

The Idea was to add it in a new DataFrame DF :

```
DF=[]
DF['DateCol']=dates
```

But it does throw the following error :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Note that I also tried DF.insert

Comment: your `DF` is a list, not a dataframe. Consider using `DF = pd.DataFrame()` to initialize an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate a **DataFrame**, not a list:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({"DateCol": dates})
```

output:

```
      DateCol
0  2022-08-19
1  2023-02-19
2  2023-08-19
3  2024-02-19
...
57 2051-02-19
58 2051-08-19
59 2052-02-19
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not creating your dataframe correctly
`DF = []` creates a list
you need `DF=pd.DataFrame()`